# android webview loadurl when screen locked

Tags: java, android, webview, timer

I have app that play music from android webview and I'v autoplay to next song, for play the next song I need load new url in webview. all working good.
But my problem was starts when I added option of playing in background from webview, I built js function that call by '@JavascriptInterface' to java function that change variable to 1 (examle nextVideo=1) [impossible load url from this function] and has timer that check every second the variable and load the next song. but when the screen is lock the webview sends js function but the java function can't load the next url, only when I open the app the next url starts load.
I spend most time in Google but no way... so if you can help me thank you vary much!

this is java timer code:

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() { //loadnextvideo
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    if (nextVideo==1) {
                        // WebView webview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
                        //webview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        webview2.loadUrl("javascript:nextVideo()");
                        nextVideo=0;
                    }}
            });}

    }, 0,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

loadUrl(url) is used to url not script. You can separate into another file .java or .kt that is used to "@AddJavascriptInterface" into that class for override function of java to javascript

**update answer kotlin version**:

```
    fun initWebView(url: String, webView: WebView) {
     val webView = WebView(this)
     val webview.settings.apply {
        useWideViewPort = true
        loadWithOverviewMode = true
        allowContentAccess = true
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        blockNetworkImage = false
        domStorageEnabled = true
        setAppCacheEnabled(true) // help load play musci on website
     }

     webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request:WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
         }
     }

     webView.loadUrl(url)
    }
```

You can load javascript from url in assets android or other website. don't forget use to cache to make load playing

Comment: But i used to load next video in script when screen unlocked and it working

Comment: I already added new function you can add url or javascript, i give you kotlin version, i hope that help you @Fox